# How to fill the blank cell with same ID

Tags: excel

I have data like this

```
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72367        Title 1  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2                          
                
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72368        Title 2  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2              
                         Step3          Resul3                            

Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72369        Title 3  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2              
                         Step3          Resul3              
                         Step4          Resul4              
                         Step5          Resul5              
                         Step6          Resul6
```

Is it possible by using Excel to fill the empty cell in column Test case ID like this? Anyways, if you have another way to modify this by using pandas, I'm so willing to apply it

```
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
72367           Title 1  Step1          Resul1      
72367                    Step2          Resul2                                          
                
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
72368           Title 2  Step1          Resul1      
72368                    Step2          Resul2              
72368                    Step3          Resul3                           

Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
72369           Title 3  Step1          Resul1      
72369                    Step2          Resul2              
72369                    Step3          Resul3              
72369                    Step4          Resul4              
72369                    Step5          Resul5              
72369                    Step6          Resul6
```

Thank you in advance